# php array file is empty when uploading file

Tags: php

when i upload file it show array file empty, however upload is on in my php.ini.

please see my code blow and let me know where is the error.

i have looked all around the web for solution but did not found, im using PHP Version  5.3.25 on centos 5.4 kernel version 2.6.18-164.el5.

thanks and regards

hadi

html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>MySQL file upload example</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form action="add_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
<p>
    <a href="list_files.php">See all files</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

add_file.php

```
<?php
// Check if a file has been uploaded
if(isset($_FILES['uploaded_file'])) {
    // Make sure the file was sent without errors
    if($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == 0) {
        // Connect to the database
        $dbLink = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'user', 'pwd', 'myTable');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        // Gather all required data
        $name = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        $mime = $dbLink->real_escape_string($_FILES['uploaded_file']['type']);
        $data = $dbLink->real_escape_string(
            file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'])
        );
        $size = intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['size']);

        // Create the SQL query
        $query = "
        INSERT INTO `file` (
            `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`, `created`
        )
        VALUES (
            '{$name}', '{$mime}', {$size}, '{$data}', NOW()
        )";

        // Execute the query
        $result = $dbLink->query($query);

        // Check if it was successfull
        if($result) {
            echo 'Success! Your file was successfully added!';
        } else {
            echo 'Error! Failed to insert the file'
            . "<pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
        }
    } else {
        echo 'An error accured while the file was being uploaded. '
        . 'Error code: '. intval($_FILES['uploaded_file']['error']);
    }

    // Close the mysql connection
    $dbLink->close();
} else {
    echo 'Error! A file was not sent!';
}

// Echo a link back to the main page
echo '<p>Click <a href="index.html">here</a> to go back</p>';
?>
```

Comment: So you're trying to upload without the use of [**move_uploaded_file( )**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) I see; not a good idea.

Comment: where us `move_uploaded_file` to upload it to server?

Comment: @Fred I believe that since he is not actually uploading the file to a server, but storing in a DB, he would not necessarily want to use move uploaded file.

Comment: hadi I believe the issue is that you are essentially trying to cast binary data to a string. You can't do that. You have to use a function like base64encode() first if you want to use php to insert binary data into a database.

Comment: @SethCohen Yes I've noticed that. So many a time have I seen the **Big Guns** here on SO, stating that it wasn't a good idea.

Comment: @Fred completely agree, storing images in a DB is not good practice, but OP asked why their code was not working, and I explained why. OP, it is not a good idea to store images in a DB.

Comment: @OP let's start by doing a `var_dump()` on all the variables involved. And if anyone else wants to jump in, please feel free. ;-)

Comment: @Fred I also agree with you, they should be placed out of web root for safety.

Comment: @SethCohen True, gotta stick to the question at hand ;-)

Comment: If you do a var dump and see lots of funny characters like question marks inside of a diamond, you need to encode the data

Comment: I heard say a day or so ago, that PDO - MySQLi do not like having spaces in between fields/arrays so I am thinking, that this line `(file_get_contents($_FILES  ['uploaded_file']        ['tmp_name']))` could be worth looking into and make it as `(file_get_contents($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']))`

Comment: i don't think i need to use base64encode(), for this matter. it should work. i have tried another script also it giving me the same error file array is empty i have used print_r($_FILES); above my file add_file.php for debugging the uploaded file it show array empty.

Comment: @ Fred space doesn't matter. i have tried that.

Comment: Theoretically, the order for uploading, with `move_uploaded_file` anyway, is that the file is first uploaded, then it uses the `tmp name`, then it is later passed as the actual name used. It seems like the order is reversed in this case.

Comment: @hadi Ok, I thought it would have been the same principle for this case. One less thing to worry about.

Comment: if you try the script at this page http://lytsp33d.com/testing/ it give array output, it work perfectly but in my system no.

Comment: @hadi I see no other mention of `created`, as opposed to `name`, `mime`, `size`, `data`

Comment: @hadi I tried uploading a simple `.txt` file with some text in it, doesn't seem like your connected to your DB. `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) in...`

Comment: @Fred i didn't get exactly what you mean, this row in the database to story name of the file the size and the actually meat data of the file data row.

Comment: @hadi You have `$name = $dbLink` and `$mime = $dbLink` and `$data = $dbLink` and `$size = intval` which match 
in `$query = "INSERT INTO 'file' ( 'name', 'mime', 'size', 'data', 'created')` except nothing about `created`.

Comment: @Fred if file uploaded successful then connecting to the database for inserting it. in my case i couldn't upload first. try to upload at your side and print array output with print_r($_FILES); above the code in add_file.php see if you get result or not.

Comment: @hadi These are the results I got after trying to upload `test_file.txt` $_POST Array ( [form_field] => ) $_FILES Array ( [uploaded_file] => Array ( [name] => test_file.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phprQACYg [error] => 0 [size] => 11 ) )
Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) in /home/content/79/11272379/html/lightspeed/testing/index.php on line 14
MySQL connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Comment: then its working in ur side, for me i didn't  get any result. i don't know why ?? did you change any thing in the script ?? did you try it in ur system or the demo i give it to you ?

Comment: @hadi How can I change anything in your script? And I tried it with the link you gave me http://lytsp33d.com/testing/ - I don't have a webserver set up, that was supposed to be sent on YOUR server. Those are the errors that YOU should be looking into. Does not look like your DB is connected.

Comment: @ Fred i thought you are debugging it at ur side. this not my server someone else server tried my script in his server and working fine, but at my box at home not working.. do you salutation why im getting array empty

Comment: @hadi I wouldn't know where to start to be honest with you. I know nothing about running a web server. I suggest you double check the connection, the DB table, etc. that's the best advice I have to give you.

Comment: @hadi Another thing. You have your action set as `add_file.php`, but when I tacked it on to the URL like this http://lytsp33d.com/testing/add_file.php it showed as a 404. If that is in fact the path/URL for the file. *"The requested URL /lightspeed/testing/add_file.php was not found on this server."*

Comment: I Recently had the same problem. Turns out that in my php ini the max file upload had no value, but it stopped working, so i just put 300 or something like that, and it now works, check if your php.ini has blank values, and set them to a specific number